# How to import OVA image to EC2 instance using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, boto

I have a virtual machine image stored in OVA format. I managed to upload one to S3 bucket using 'boto' Python library, but I cannot find anywhere in documentation and boto source how to import and  start it on EC2.

The idea is to automatically upload VMs from my laptop to EC2 and deploy/start/stop them within one script.

Did anyone do anything like this?
Thank you.

Comment: `boto` has no support to import OVF image.

Comment: @helloV so probably there's another way to import/start/stop/delete VMs from OVA image to EC2? I'm totally new to AWS so have to ask stupid questions

Comment: Yes. Use AWS CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-image.html